# Update text in real time by calling two functions Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have program that takes input from the user and displays multiple variations of the input using the `Population()` function. The `store_fit` function adds these different variations to a list then deletes them so that the list is only populated with one variation at a time.

I want to be able to get the variation from the list and use it to update my text. However, my program only updates the text after the `Population` function is completed. How could I run the `Population` function and update my text simultaneously?

code:

```
fit = []
...

def store_fit(fittest): # fittest is each variation from Population
    clear.fit()
    fit.append(fittest)
...

pg.init()
...
done = False

while not done:
...
    if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:
        print(text)
        target = text
        Population(1000) #1000 variations
        store_fit(value)
        # I want this to run at the same time as Population
        fittest = fit[0]
...
top_sentence = font.render(("test: " + fittest), 1, pg.Color('lightskyblue3'))
screen.blit(top_sentence, (400, 400))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to make `Population` a generator function. See [The Python yield keyword explained](https://pythontips.com/2013/09/29/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/):

```py
def Populate(text, c):
    for i in range(c):

        # compute variation
        # [...]

        yield variation
```

Create an iterator and use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to retrieve the next variation in the loop, so you can print every single variation:

```py
populate_iter = Populate(text, 1000)

final_variation = None
while not done:

    next_variation = next(populate_iter, None)
    if next_variation :
        final_variation = next_variation 

        # print current variation
        # [...]

    else:
        done = True
```

Edit according to the comment:

> In order to keep my question simple, I didn't mention that `Population`, was a class [...]

Of course `Populate can be a class`, too. I this case you've to implement the [`object.__iter__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) method. e.g.:

```py
class Populate:
    def __init__(self, text, c):
        self.text = text
        self.c    = c

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self.c):

            # compute variation
            # [...]

            yield variation
```

Create an iterator by [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter). e.g.:

```py
populate_iter = iter(Populate(text, 1000))

final_variation = None
while not done:

    next_variation = next(populate_iter, None)
    if next_variation :
        final_variation = next_variation 

        # print current variation
        # [...]

    else:
        done = True
```

Comment: That's the right way to go IMHO. I used a similiar approach in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53589557/142637

Comment: In order to keep my question simple, I didn't mention that `Population`, was  a class and its `__init__` function is what is calling the other functions. When I try and yield inside of the `__init__` I am told that it should not return a generator. Is there any way around this?