# Use a generator within a while loop to blit text onto the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I have a class that initializes a population of the same word in different variations then over time rearranges the letters into the desired word. In pygame I'm trying to have the current word be displayed onto the screen then change depending on what variation the class is on in real time. The problem I'm facing is being able to call the class and update the screen at the same time.

I was told that I should use a generator and yield the variation and then enter back into the main loop, however this does not work since my `Population` class does all of the work within a while loop inside of it's `__init__`.

How could I yield the current variation that I want to change the text being blit onto the screen within the main loop?

code:

```
class Population:
    def __init__(self, size):
        ...
        while variation.fitness < len(target): # unknown amount of variations
            self.selection() # restarts selection process
...
pg.init()
top = ''
...
while not done:
    ...
    if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:
        Population(1000)
        top = # I want to make this variable be the current variation within Popualtion
    ...
    top_sentence = font.render((top), 1, pg.Color('blue'))
    screen.blit(top_sentence, (400,400))
```

Comment: "since my Population class does all of the work within a while loop inside of it's __init__" - why? Why should this be a class at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you continuously create a new `Population` object in the loop? It is a class, so you can add interfaces (methods) to communicate with the object and to commit and retrieve data. The statement `self.selection()` hast to be in a method of the class rather than the constructor. See the concept of [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Create a method (e.g. `NextVariation`) which does a single call to `self.selection()` rather than multiple "selections" in a loop. The method returns the current variation. The method doesn't need an inner loop, because it is called continuously in the main application loop:

```
class Population:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        # [...]

    def SetTarget(self, target):
        self.target = target 

    def NextVariation(self):
        if variation.fitness < len(self.target): # unknown amount of variations
            self.selection() # restarts selection process

        return variation # return current variation
```

```py
population = Population(1000)
top = ''

while not done:
    # [...]

    if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:

        population.SetTarget(...)

    top = population.NextVariation()

    # [...]
    top_sentence = font.render((top), 1, pg.Color('blue'))
    screen.blit(top_sentence, (400,400))
```

This can also be with an iterator that `yield`s the variations, as demonstrated in the answer to your previous question - [Update text in real time by calling two functions Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046380/update-text-in-real-time-by-calling-two-functions-pygame)

---

Note, alternatively it is even possible to create a new instance of the class when <kbd>return</kbd> is pressed. But it depends on your need if you need to create a new object, which restart to process, or if you just want to change a parameter  of the process:

```py
population = Population(1000)
top = ''

while not done:
    # [...]

    if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:

        population = Population(...)

    top = population.NextVariation()

    # [...]
    top_sentence = font.render((top), 1, pg.Color('blue'))
    screen.blit(top_sentence, (400,400))
```

Comment: This is great but I have a variable `target` that I assign a value when pressing enter. If I create an instance of `Population` outside of the the main loop then I would have to hard code the value of target. Is there any way to change the value of `target ` inside the main loop then make an instance of `Population`?

Comment: @yemi.JUMP You've methods. I've added SetTarget to the answer. An alternative is to create a new instance of the class when the key is pressed. But it depends on your needs, which solution is the way to go for you.